# How to configuring PAM to use different language / locale settings

Tags: server, language-support, locale, pam

Currently we are using a database client with a ISO-8859-1 character set.
The Ubuntu server is running with de_DE.utf8. If the user uses a username or password containing other characters than 7-bit ascii, we are in trouble.

/etc/pam.d/informix

```
#
# Then PAM configuration file for the Shadow `informix' service
#

# More verbose
auth    required        pam_warn.so debug

# Environment
auth    required        pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/opt/IBM/informix/etc/locale user_readenv=0

# Disallows other than root logins when /etc/nologin exists
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so

# Standard Un*x authentication.
@include common-auth
```

/opt/IBM/informix/etc/locale

```
LANG="de_DE"
LC_CTYPE="de_DE"
LC_ALL="de_DE"
```

But the PAM configuration does not work:

/var/log/auth.log (with a password containing non 7-bit ascii)

```
Jul 19 15:46:54 myhost oninit: pam_warn(informix:auth): function=[pam_sm_authenticate] service=[informix] terminal=[<unknown>] user=[myuser] ruser=[myuser] rhost=[myclient]
Jul 19 15:46:54 myhost oninit: [lsass-pam] [module:pam_lsass]pam_sm_authenticate error [login:myuser][error code:40067]
```

I also tried LANG=de_DE.iso88591 in the /opt/IBM/informix/etc/locale without any success. Whats is wrong ?

Comment: Did you generate the ISO-8859-1 locale? `sudo locale-gen de_DE` (it's not there by default).

Comment: Yes:


#locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
de_AT.utf8
de_BE.utf8
de_CH.utf8
de_DE
de_DE.iso88591
de_DE.utf8
de_LI.utf8
de_LU.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX

Comment: I'm certainly not an expert, but have to ask if you know that the approach is supposed to work. IIUC, the password still contains UTF-8 encoded characters, while you try to tell it to interpret it as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: I have verified with tcpdump, that the informix client is definitely using ISO-8859-1 characters for user and password, while the pam module still using a different charset.

Comment: I have written a tiny and simple C pam plugin to write out the content of the username and plain password as well as the environment. Username and password are ISO-8859-1 characters and pam_env.so does not change the environment to ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a self written PAM-Module

```
.
.
/* Convert charset */
iso2utf((char*) pUsername, (char*) &szuser, sizeof(szuser));
iso2utf((char*) pPassword, (char*) &szpass, sizeof(szpass));

/* Setting pam items */
pam_set_item(pamh, PAM_USER, (char*) &szuser);
pam_set_item(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, (char*) &szpass);
.
.
```

it works fine:

```
#
# Then PAM configuration file for the Shadow `informix' service
#

# Informix user + password conversion
auth    sufficient      informix_pam.so

# Disallows other than root logins when /etc/nologin exists
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so

# LDAP authentication
auth    required        pam_lsass.so try_first_pass
```